# Flutter custom carousel type synced ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm working on a Flutter project and I'm aiming to implement a synchronized carousel-type ListView with the following features:

**Upper Month List**:

- Displays all months extracted from the dummyData list.
  Implements a carousel effect where the month becomes larger when coming to the center from the right or left.

**MasonryGridView**:

- Displays images based on date & time, currently appearing in a seemingly random order.

**Synchronization**:

- When the MasonryGridView is horizontally scrolled, the Upper Month List should scroll accordingly to display the corresponding month.
- Scrolling the Upper Month List should also trigger a synchronized scroll in the MasonryGridView.

I've attached a few design images for clarity. Any guidance or code snippets on achieving this synchronized carousel effect would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Code:

```
class GridScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const GridScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                // Previous month container
                Container(
                  height: 23,
                  width: 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.horizontal(
                      right: Radius.circular(12),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Divider
                Expanded(
                  child: Divider(
                    thickness: 3,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    indent: 9,
                    endIndent: 9,
                  ),
                ),

                // Middle month container
                Container(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 90,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xfff5f5f5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                      12,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'April',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // Divider
                Expanded(
                  child: Divider(
                    thickness: 3,
                    color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                    indent: 9,
                    endIndent: 9,
                  ),
                ),

                // Next month container
                Container(
                  height: 23,
                  width: 20,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.horizontal(
                      left: Radius.circular(12),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: MasonryGridView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: dummyData.length,
        gridDelegate: const SliverSimpleGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final dummyMeta = dummyData[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: [
                  Image(
                    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                      dummyMeta['content'],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      dummyMeta['created_on'],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Dummy Data List

```
List<Map> dummyData = [
  // Jan
  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704377133466-784bc482e366?q=80&w=3087&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-01-01 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797661-9e0c87f59c60?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-05-01 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695798522-6e208131916d?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-15-01 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704281657567-ed059c3e75a3?q=80&w=2942&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-20-01 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797507-d44d838b0ac7?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-25-01 14:32:46',
  },

  // Feb
  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704377133466-784bc482e366?q=80&w=3087&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-01-02 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797661-9e0c87f59c60?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-05-02 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695798522-6e208131916d?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-15-02 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704281657567-ed059c3e75a3?q=80&w=2942&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-20-02 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797507-d44d838b0ac7?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-25-02 14:32:46',
  },

  // March
  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704377133466-784bc482e366?q=80&w=3087&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-01-03 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797661-9e0c87f59c60?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-05-03 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695798522-6e208131916d?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-15-03 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704281657567-ed059c3e75a3?q=80&w=2942&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-20-03 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797507-d44d838b0ac7?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-25-03 14:32:46',
  },

  // April
  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704377133466-784bc482e366?q=80&w=3087&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-01-04 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797661-9e0c87f59c60?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-05-04 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695798522-6e208131916d?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-15-04 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704281657567-ed059c3e75a3?q=80&w=2942&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-20-04 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797507-d44d838b0ac7?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-25-04 14:32:46',
  },

  // July
  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704377133466-784bc482e366?q=80&w=3087&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-01-07 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797661-9e0c87f59c60?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-05-07 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695798522-6e208131916d?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-15-07 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704281657567-ed059c3e75a3?q=80&w=2942&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-20-07 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797507-d44d838b0ac7?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-25-07 14:32:46',
  },

  // October
  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704377133466-784bc482e366?q=80&w=3087&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-01-10 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797661-9e0c87f59c60?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-05-10 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695798522-6e208131916d?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-15-10 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704281657567-ed059c3e75a3?q=80&w=2942&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-20-10 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797507-d44d838b0ac7?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-25-10 14:32:46',
  },

  // December
  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704377133466-784bc482e366?q=80&w=3087&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-01-12 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797661-9e0c87f59c60?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-05-12 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695798522-6e208131916d?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-15-12 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1704281657567-ed059c3e75a3?q=80&w=2942&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-20-12 14:32:46',
  },

  {
    'post_type': 'image',
    'content':
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685797507-d44d838b0ac7?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
    'created_on': '2024-25-12 14:32:46',
  },
];
```

[image]

Comment: If the second list is random, how are you going to place items in second list when first list item is selected? Like if user select April, there could be items in second list which belongs to April but they are further apart.

Comment: I'll be retrieving data for both the month list and the image metadata list from the database. My goal is to implement a scrollable feature. Feel free to ask if you have any questions or need further clarification. Thank you! @Rahul